# Pushing data to table detailview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing a drilldown tableview,

I created the two tables, and I am able to display and pass data using json;
my first tableview has play objects but when i click an object item (say play 1), i want to display characters,
a play has a atitle, genre and date

In mysql database; I have several different plays and each of them have several characters each. Everything else is working, except this;

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    play.ids = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    play.title= [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
    play.genre=[[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"genre"];
    play.date= [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSString *characters=[[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"character"];
    sCharacters2= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:characters, nil];

    play.characters=sCharacters2;        

   [playList addObject:play];  
}
```

This only prints the last play,

but I want it to print all the plays
anything I am doing wrong?

Got it, Got, for those who may encounter such a problem, you need to create a new object, so in this case, I should have created a new play object after for statement

Comment: What you did so far ?

Comment: @mutawe-- I have updated what I have done so far

Comment: this doesnt sound like a bad question after all, I wonder why it was marked down so fast.

Answer (score -1):

For the showing data on tableview you can use simple method of [tableview](http://www.guilmo.com/how-to-create-a-simple-uitableview-with-static-data/)

and for data passing between view controllers you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1)

Comment: Nope. The problem is that the OP was modifying the same object in each loop of the array rather than creating a new object.

Comment: Question was updated, i have answer that question before updation.